# c# Bluetooth - an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, printing, bluetooth

We have a program that communicate with Zebra printers. This program runs on WM devices (Motorola ES400), and with MZ320 is very reliable but not with iMZ320. On the devices we use BluetoothClient (InTheHand). On iMZ320 the program throws very often an exception.

Before the error message appears the program waits 80 seconds. (But only on ES400 - an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine). The printer shows that the bluetooth connection is open (blue LED) during this time. If the printer is off we get another message but after only 6 seconds (no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it). After this happens, the program on ES400 can not communicate with iMZ until we restart the printer.

Question: Does anybody have an idea why is it happening and what can we do?

**Sample Code:**

```
    public static Boolean BluetoothPrintES400(String label)
    {

      BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

      BluetoothAddress btAddress;
      btAddress = BluetoothAddress.Parse("ab465as34jd3");
      BluetoothClient btClient = new BluetoothClient();

      try
          {
              btClient.Connect(new BluetoothEndPoint(btAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort));
          }
      catch (Exception ex)
          {
              message = ex.Message;
              return false;
          }
      Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2");

      label = label + "\r\n";
          int x, y;
          for (int i = 0; i < ((int)(label.Length / 500)) + 1; i++)
          {
              x = i * 500;
              y = 500;
              if ((x + y) > label.Length)
              {
                  y = label.Length - x;
              }
              byte[] configLabel = e.GetBytes(label.ToCharArray(), x, y);
              //connection.Write(configLabel);
              NetworkStream ns = btClient.GetStream();
              ns.Write(configLabel, 0, configLabel.Length);
          }

       btClient.Close();

       return true;
    }
```

**First exception after ~80 seconds:**

Message:

```
    An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Stacktrace:

```
    - System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectNoCheck()
    - System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect()
    - InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient.Connect()
    - Project.Utility.Util.BluetoothPrintES400()
    - Project.Forms.FrmMain.printing()
    - Project.Forms.FrmMain.mniNext_Click()
    - System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
    - Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
    - Project.Program.Main()
```

**Second exception after ~6 seconds** when i try to print again:

Message:

```
    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Stacktrace:

```
    - System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectNoCheck()
    - System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect()
    - InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient.Connect()
    - Project.Utility.Util.BluetoothPrintES400()
    - Project.Forms.FrmMain.printing()
    - Project.Forms.FrmMain.mniNext_Click()
    - System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
    - Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
    - System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
    - Project.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Provide a sample code and ecxeption line.

Comment: The iMZ line made a lot of changes under the covers with its CPCL & ZPL protocols that weren't transparent, such as a soft-cycle of the MZ takes about 5 seconds but the iMZ takes 20+ sec due to the new software stacks built in. Also noticed the MDM won't work unless the device is toggled to ZPL mode but not Line Mode. I've implemented the MZ and iMZ over 802.11 but not BT so I don't have much advice to offer other than work with your Zebra rep closely and ask a lot of questions.